# Jupyter server extension url pattern in azure notebook

Tags: python, azure, jupyter

I am writing a Jupyter server extension to convert notebook as a web api. It works well in local computer.  I have some problem to deploy to the free azure notebook.  I cannot figure out the url pattern or my server extension is not loaded.

I have installed my package in Azure Notebooks terminal for python2.7 while kernal configure to use python 3.xx.  command:

```
  pip27 install jupyterexcel --user
  jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterexcel
```

I can see the extension is enable by using

```
  jupyter serverextension list
```

My problem is when I start my notebook:

```
https://jupyterexcel-luozhijian.notebooks.azure.com/j/notebooks/TestingJupyter.ipynb
```

I cannot figure out how to get the server extension url pattern to work. 
In my local computer, I can use:

```
http://localhost:8888/Excel/TestingJupyter.ipynb?token=ABCD&functionname=sum&1=11&2=8&3=6
```

The server_extension code is in:
https://github.com/luozhijian/jupyterexcel/blob/master/jupyterexcel/server_extension.py

```
class ExcelModeHandler(IPythonHandler):
    pass
    #some code here 

def load_jupyter_server_extension(nbapp):
    web_app = nbapp.web_app
    host_pattern = '.*$'
    route_pattern = url_path_join(web_app.settings['base_url'], r'/Excel%s' % path_regex)
    web_app.add_handlers(host_pattern, [(route_pattern, ExcelModeHandler)])
```

It will not work if i use such as:

```
https://jupyterexcel-luozhijian.notebooks.azure.com/Excel/j/notebooks/TestingJupyter.ipynb?token=ABCD&functionname=sum&1=11&2=8&3=6
It said page not found.  
I expected it return json with: 25.0
```

Comment: I found that server extension now is not supported in:
https://notebooks.azure.com/Microsoft/projects/nbextensions/html/InstallExtension.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your scenario! Azure Notebooks does not support Jupyter server extensions, but we will add this to our backlog. I'll be sure to update if we can continue to hear asks for this and are able to prioritize this feature work. Thanks!